# What's a good writing software for Android phones/tablets?

Tags: software, mobile

Everyone once in a while while I'm out I come up with something I want to add to my story. Are there any good writing apps for Android phones and tablets? Most places that recommend mobile writing software recommend iPhone apps, but what about the thousands of people who use Android powered phones?

Answer (score 8):

Springpad isn't a "writing app," but it's a great note taking app for Android and Chrome. Not only can you write notes, but you take pictures, record audio, and organize everything into notebooks.

Comment: springpad <3 all you need is love !

Answer (score 7):

Hmmm, I used to use Documents to Go, but now that Google Docs are editable on the phone now I just use that.

Comment: Does Google have an app for Google Docs now or just the website?

Comment: The website is able to run on Android, but Google does not have an official Docs app (yet).

Comment: Google does have an official Docs app now for Android (it's in the Market).

Comment: The app is a bit flaky, though. And offline access never works for me.

Answer (score 3):

It is perhaps worth pointing out that in the 6.5 years since the question was originally asked, Microsoft had made Word available on Android. Whatever you think of Word as a writing app, there is an obvious appeal to cross platform software with files in a shared space. Ditto for OneNote for the note-taking and organizing aspects of the task.

Answer (score 2):

There is an app I have on my phone called [A Novel Idea](http://learningworksforkids.com/apps/a-novel-idea/).  Not sure if it is still around but it works exactly like scrivener but for the phone.  Gives you options for character bios, chaptering, pretty much everything you would want in a novel software.

EDIT: In adding a link for it, I saw that it was for iOS only but maybe it could be beneficial for others who are looking.