# Software for analyzing a manuscript?

Tags: software, tools, text-analysis

I would like to get a better picture of a manuscript I've written, especially in regards to word usage patterns and potentially overused terms.

I'm curious whether anyone can recommend a document analysis tool.

Specifically, is there a program that takes a Microsoft Word document and produces a spreadsheet of all the words contained in the document and the number of times the word appears?

e.g.

> `cat    23`
>
> `said   15`
>
> `jumped 12`
>
> `dog    7`

Comment: I'll edit to clarify intent. I've seen other discussion regarding writing tools, such as http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/2050, http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1854 and http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1970

Comment: yes, that helps some.  A document analysis tool doesn't have to have a writing focus is all I was thinking.

Comment: I am also interested in upcoming answers. Good question.

Comment: Writing a program to count the instances of words in a text file was a programming project I had in college! Sorry, just had to jump in with that  :P. But it should be fairly simple for programmers to implement or write - if none of the programs give you the kind of output you want I'd be happy to try to help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bing search for word frequency gets these two promising programs. Not for Word documents, but that's not a huge problem since you can save as text or copy-paste.

http://wordfrequencycounter.com/

Another:
http://www.primitivezone.com/primitive-word-counter.html

I'm actually writing a writing app for Windows now. It'd be pretty easy to add frequency in as a tool... Hmm.

Answer (score 11):

The writing program yWriter has this function. [yWriter](http://www.spacejock.com/yWriter5.html) is basically a downgraded version of Scrivener for Windows. It allows you to create multiple scenes and rearrange them easily. It will also analyze those scenes or the entire document for word usage, word goal, etc.

Comment: thank you! That works like a charm! Wow, as if I needed another reason to love Scrivener. I should have RTFM more thoroughly.

Comment: Scrivener has the same feature? Awesome!

Comment: Project --> Text Statistics. Gives you exactly the list Jen is looking for. I had no idea I used "the" over two thousand times. :)

Comment: Squeeee! I <3 Scrivener! I'm so glad they came out with a Windows version.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't precisely what you're looking for, but it's interesting:

http://www.wordle.net/

Answer (score 1):

Scrivener, a program by literature and latte, will help with this. This is just one of the features--it's super-advanced and a complete lifesaver for anyone writing anything. I use it for scripts and novels, and sometimes just for its organization and fullscreen for my papers. It's amazing. Free trial lasts a while, but it's always in beta so you can usually get it w/o paying :)
scrivener: www.literatureandlatte.com/scrivener.html